# Exit() in wordpress after form submit

Tags: php, wordpress, email, redirect

I have a form in wordpress, and all the values filled in the form are used to send an email to an administrator.

All this works well. I receive the email, but after running the script to send the email, I need to redirect the user to another location obviously.

After running the mail script I use this to redirect the user:

```
header("location: " . home_url() . "");
exit();
```

But it seems the `exit()` is causing me trouble. Like it trigger not to load the rest of the page.

Any help is **greatly** appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wp redirect

```
<?php
wp_redirect( $location, $status );
exit;
?>
```

more about

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. I tried it with `wp_redirect`, but didn't seem to work either. All I had to do was to place the redirecting part on top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the wordpress method for redirects. `wp_redirect` is your answer

```
wp_redirect(home_url());
exit;
```

documentation for `wp_redirect()` can be found here: [wordpress reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
wp_redirect(get_permalink(ID));
```